# SVG button without CSS doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm making a svg button with animated gradient in mouseover event, without CSS.

The button listen to mouseout and mouseover events, without any problem, changing the radialGradient attribute between id="rellenoZoomHover" and id="rellenoZoom", depending on the listener answer.

The button has an  tag in it radialGradient declaration tag, that repeats only one time.

The problem is that the script only execute the first time: second time, ignores animate.

Whath I am doing wrong?. Thanks in advance

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<svg version='1.1' id='project' xmlns:svg='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
        xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
        xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
onload='init(evt)'>
<script type='text/ecmascript'>
 
 function init(evt) {
  cmdButtonZoomPrevio = document.getElementById('cmdZoomPrevio');
  cmdButtonZoomPrevio.addEventListener('mouseover', manejadorDeMouseHoverEnBotones);
  cmdButtonZoomPrevio.addEventListener('mouseout', manejadorDeMouseOutEnBotones); 
 }

 <![CDATA[
 
 function manejadorDeMouseHoverEnBotones(evt) {
  var pathVolatil = cmdButtonZoomPrevio.childNodes[1];
  pathVolatil.setAttribute('fill','url(#rellenoZoomHover)');
 }
 
 function manejadorDeMouseOutEnBotones(evt) {  
  var pathVolatil = cmdButtonZoomPrevio.childNodes[1];
  pathVolatil.setAttribute('fill','url(#rellenoZoom)');
 }

 //El botón cmdZoomPrevio;
 var cmdButtonZoomPrevio;
]]>

</script>
 
  <g id="cmdZoomPrevio" class="boton" toggleButton="false" triStateButton="false"> 
   <path id="bordeZoomSE" fill="url(#rellenoZoom)" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
    M64.925,85.116c3.529,0,7.005-0.938,10.042-2.69c9.609-5.554,12.924-17.858,7.354-27.479l34.848-20.112
    c16.633,28.863,6.753,65.771-22.063,82.438c-9.188,5.294-19.581,8.093-30.167,8.093L64.925,85.116L64.925,85.116z"/>
   <g id="dibujocmdZoomSE">
    <rect x="105.766" y="97.561" transform="matrix(0.8707 -0.4918 0.4918 0.8707 -34.1811 65.8925)" fill="#333333" width="4.92" height="0.784"/>
    <polygon fill="#663300" points="104.234,87.553 109.439,96.827 109.439,96.897 106.586,98.467 106.518,98.467 101.313,89.191 
    101.313,89.118 104.165,87.553    "/>
    <rect x="101.312" y="86.085" transform="matrix(0.8715 -0.4904 0.4904 0.8715 -29.6865 61.2979)" width="1.641" height="2.429"/>
    <polygon fill="#006633" points="98.104,99.394 88.091,93.723 88.091,93.651 98.068,87.73 98.139,87.765 98.139,99.358    "/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#006633" stroke-width="2.15" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="3" d="
    M98.104,93.543h0.854c3.382,0,6.298-0.593,8.771-1.783c2.373-1.182,3.586-2.61,3.643-4.281c-0.057-1.665-1.262-3.063-3.643-4.203
    c-2.474-1.23-5.391-1.854-8.771-1.854c-3.467,0-6.413,0.616-8.835,1.854c-0.139,0.047-0.288,0.117-0.432,0.213"/>
    <path fill="#CCFFFF" d="M97.752,86.978c-2.122-0.014-3.947-0.788-5.49-2.313c-1.463-1.474-2.184-3.263-2.174-5.354
    c-0.01-2.103,0.714-3.925,2.174-5.457c1.531-1.458,3.348-2.183,5.454-2.179c2.113-0.006,3.911,0.717,5.38,2.179
    c1.535,1.527,2.313,3.354,2.314,5.457c-0.006,2.105-0.779,3.892-2.314,5.354C101.635,86.195,99.85,86.966,97.752,86.978z"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#0000FF" stroke-width="1.4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="3" d="
    M97.752,86.978c-2.096,0-3.9-0.761-5.42-2.288c-1.475-1.474-2.219-3.229-2.219-5.271c0-2.09,0.744-3.9,2.219-5.421
    c1.52-1.479,3.324-2.226,5.42-2.226c2.089,0,3.873,0.738,5.344,2.226c1.522,1.475,2.285,3.271,2.285,5.421
    c0,2.048-0.758,3.807-2.285,5.271C101.622,86.217,99.841,86.978,97.752,86.978z"/>
   </g>
  
   <defs>
    <radialGradient id="rellenoZoomHover" cx="65" cy="65" r="65"  gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
     <stop offset="0.5" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF">
      <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#FFFFFF;#81BEF7" dur="2s" repeatCount="1"/> 
      </stop>
     <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#81BEF7"/>
    </radialGradient>
     
    <radialGradient id="rellenoZoom" cx="65" cy="65" r="65" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
     <stop offset="0.5" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF" />
     <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#A4A4A4"/>
    </radialGradient>
   </defs>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document has a timeline that begins at 0 and stays at 0 unless some animation runs. As an animation runs the timeline advances, in this case to 2 seconds as we have 2 seconds of animation.

The next time we hover the animation timeline is at 2 seconds, so the animation does not trigger again as the animation's start time has passed.

We could either

1. manually trigger the animation with javascript by calling beginElement(), this would affect just one animation
2. force the document timeline back to 0 this would affect all animations.

The code below demonstrates both (2. is commented out as we only need one technique)

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<svg version='1.1' id='project' xmlns:svg='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
        xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
        xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
onload='init(evt)'>
<script type='text/ecmascript'>
 
 function init(evt) {
  cmdButtonZoomPrevio = document.getElementById('cmdZoomPrevio');
  cmdButtonZoomPrevio.addEventListener('mouseover', manejadorDeMouseHoverEnBotones);
  cmdButtonZoomPrevio.addEventListener('mouseout', manejadorDeMouseOutEnBotones); 
 }

 <![CDATA[
 
 function manejadorDeMouseHoverEnBotones(evt) {
  var pathVolatil = cmdButtonZoomPrevio.childNodes[1];
  pathVolatil.setAttribute('fill','url(#rellenoZoomHover)');
        document.getElementById('rellenoZoomHoverAnimate').beginElement();
        //document.getElementById('project').setCurrentTime(0);
 }
 
 function manejadorDeMouseOutEnBotones(evt) {  
  var pathVolatil = cmdButtonZoomPrevio.childNodes[1];
  pathVolatil.setAttribute('fill','url(#rellenoZoom)');
 }

 //El botón cmdZoomPrevio;
 var cmdButtonZoomPrevio;
]]>

</script>
 
  <g id="cmdZoomPrevio" class="boton" toggleButton="false" triStateButton="false"> 
   <path id="bordeZoomSE" fill="url(#rellenoZoom)" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
    M64.925,85.116c3.529,0,7.005-0.938,10.042-2.69c9.609-5.554,12.924-17.858,7.354-27.479l34.848-20.112
    c16.633,28.863,6.753,65.771-22.063,82.438c-9.188,5.294-19.581,8.093-30.167,8.093L64.925,85.116L64.925,85.116z"/>
   <g id="dibujocmdZoomSE">
    <rect x="105.766" y="97.561" transform="matrix(0.8707 -0.4918 0.4918 0.8707 -34.1811 65.8925)" fill="#333333" width="4.92" height="0.784"/>
    <polygon fill="#663300" points="104.234,87.553 109.439,96.827 109.439,96.897 106.586,98.467 106.518,98.467 101.313,89.191 
    101.313,89.118 104.165,87.553    "/>
    <rect x="101.312" y="86.085" transform="matrix(0.8715 -0.4904 0.4904 0.8715 -29.6865 61.2979)" width="1.641" height="2.429"/>
    <polygon fill="#006633" points="98.104,99.394 88.091,93.723 88.091,93.651 98.068,87.73 98.139,87.765 98.139,99.358    "/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#006633" stroke-width="2.15" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="3" d="
    M98.104,93.543h0.854c3.382,0,6.298-0.593,8.771-1.783c2.373-1.182,3.586-2.61,3.643-4.281c-0.057-1.665-1.262-3.063-3.643-4.203
    c-2.474-1.23-5.391-1.854-8.771-1.854c-3.467,0-6.413,0.616-8.835,1.854c-0.139,0.047-0.288,0.117-0.432,0.213"/>
    <path fill="#CCFFFF" d="M97.752,86.978c-2.122-0.014-3.947-0.788-5.49-2.313c-1.463-1.474-2.184-3.263-2.174-5.354
    c-0.01-2.103,0.714-3.925,2.174-5.457c1.531-1.458,3.348-2.183,5.454-2.179c2.113-0.006,3.911,0.717,5.38,2.179
    c1.535,1.527,2.313,3.354,2.314,5.457c-0.006,2.105-0.779,3.892-2.314,5.354C101.635,86.195,99.85,86.966,97.752,86.978z"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#0000FF" stroke-width="1.4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="3" d="
    M97.752,86.978c-2.096,0-3.9-0.761-5.42-2.288c-1.475-1.474-2.219-3.229-2.219-5.271c0-2.09,0.744-3.9,2.219-5.421
    c1.52-1.479,3.324-2.226,5.42-2.226c2.089,0,3.873,0.738,5.344,2.226c1.522,1.475,2.285,3.271,2.285,5.421
    c0,2.048-0.758,3.807-2.285,5.271C101.622,86.217,99.841,86.978,97.752,86.978z"/>
   </g>
  
   <defs>
    <radialGradient id="rellenoZoomHover" cx="65" cy="65" r="65"  gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
     <stop offset="0.5" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF">
      <animate id="rellenoZoomHoverAnimate" attributeName="stop-color" values="#FFFFFF;#81BEF7" dur="2s" repeatCount="1"/> 
      </stop>
     <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#81BEF7"/>
    </radialGradient>
     
    <radialGradient id="rellenoZoom" cx="65" cy="65" r="65" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
     <stop offset="0.5" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF" />
     <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#A4A4A4"/>
    </radialGradient>
   </defs>
  </g>
</svg>
```